keyboard keys randomly not working
I started having weird issues with my laptop keyboard. Some keys would stop working randomly and then start working after a while or after pressing them several times. I don't think it comes from dirt. The problem seems to go away when using an external keyboard plugged in via USB.
Might be something wrong with the drivers? Would be great if you could help me fixing this.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and I had just re-installed Linux a couple of months ago. Laptop is an HP Elitebook.
Cheers for any help!
